# How to pass table name dynamically in select query for sql connector in mulesoft?

Tags: dynamic-sql, mulesoft

I have a select connector in my mulesoft web API and I want to fetch data using SQL query but I need to pass table name dynamically.

I tried $(vars.table) but it is not working.

```
#["Select * FROM $(vars.tableName)"]
```

Should execute the SQL query successfully and fetch the records from the database.

Answer (score 0):

Try this , its working for me

```
#['SELECT * FROM ($(vars.vTablename))']
```